# AS3 preloader showing 0% until complete

Tags: actionscript-3, text, preloader

I've seen similar questions with preloaders stuck at 90% or showing blank altogether, however mine, as usual, works inside flash - trace statement shows % progression, and when loading is slow the preloader displays the % progression as meant to.

Then once uploaded online, the preloader shows 0% statically for seconds, all the way until the content is loaded, rendering the preloader half meaningless.

The preloader weighs 2-4 kb.

Why won't the percentage number increase from 0% once on the server?

Comment: Do you use IE11 when testing? IE11 is notorious for this behavior on preloaders. I don't have data on Firefoxes, but they don't seem to alter their behavior.

Comment: Are you using preloader in main flash file and does your flash contains lots of movieclip exported for actionscript on frame1?

Comment: How are you checking expected total bytes of item to be loaded? Is the number correct before you start any preloader updates? **If not** then that could be the problem. PS: I hope you're not still trying to get an SWF to measure the loading of itself. You need one SWF to act as preloader (measure bytes downloaded), it has one job to check the **progressEvent** for bytes loaded (of next content) and show a percentage. You need a second file (SWF? MP3? Jpeg? etc) that is to be loaded and measured (in this case the main content (frame 2 etc) of your SWF in a separate SWF file.

Comment: Sry, late here. The problem happens in both chrome and firefox. And VC. One yes, I'm using the preloader in a separate file, using progressevent and calling urlloader to load a separate swf, that's why it weighs only 2-4kb. So again, inside flash the trace statement shows % progression as does the preloader, but just won't online, does host matter?

Comment: All we know is '90%' of people seem to have a problems with these AS preloaders, funny how a seemingly black/white issue has no straightforward answer, i.e. works inside flash does not work on web page/online, as if the as code gets corrupted upon embedding or something.

Comment: Is your second swf using RSL's? I am not 100% sure but I remember it caused my preloaders to stuck for couple seconds